# C# WebBrowser Control - ignore website security warnings

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, browser, webbrowser-control

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable “Security Alert” window in Webbrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178578/how-to-disable-security-alert-window-in-webbrowser-control)

I'm currently using WebBrowser (System.Windows.Forms) in my program. When I try to access some websites over https, the message "There is a problem with your websites security certificate" appears. Is there any way I can get WebBrowser to ignore these types of warnings?

There are solutions for WebClient: [How to ignore a certificate error with c# 2.0 WebClient - without the certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301127/how-to-ignore-a-certificate-error-with-c-2-0-webclient-without-the-certificate)
But those solutions do not apply to this problem, as WebBrowser seems to ignore whatever is set in ServicePointManager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/WebBrowserControlDialogs.aspx from the question [Access Intranet via SSL using WebBrowser Winforms Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124885/access-intranet-via-ssl-using-webbrowser-winforms-control/313077#313077)