# Ignoring web browser certificate errors in a webbrowser

Tags: c#, winforms, ssl, browser, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to Ignore web browser certificate errors in a webbrowser which appear in the web browser like below.

[image]

I'm trying to use [this](http://jiangsheng.net/2013/07/17/howto-ignoring-web-browser-certificate-errors-in-webbrowser-host/) solution (see below code also) but it didn't worked for me, the certificate error dialog box still is displayed. My guess is: Does have to do I'm getting [that](http://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/support/docs/voice-unified-communications/unified-contact-center-express/112189-uccx-certificate-error-01.gif) dialog box rather than a pagine like [this](http://www.sslshopper.com/assets/images/for_different_site.gif)?

C# Code (take from article):

```
[Guid("6D5140C1-7436-11CE-8034-00AA006009FA")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
[ComImport]
public interface UCOMIServiceProvider
{
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    [PreserveSig]
    int QueryService(
        [In] ref Guid guidService,
        [In] ref Guid riid,
        [Out] out IntPtr ppvObject);
}
[ComImport()]
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("79eac9d5-bafa-11ce-8c82-00aa004ba90b")]
[InterfaceTypeAttribute(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IWindowForBindingUI
{
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    [PreserveSig]
    int GetWindow(
        [In] ref Guid rguidReason,
        [In, Out] ref IntPtr phwnd);
}
[ComImport()]
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("79eac9d7-bafa-11ce-8c82-00aa004ba90b")]
[InterfaceTypeAttribute(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IHttpSecurity
{
    //derived from IWindowForBindingUI
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    [PreserveSig]
    int GetWindow(
        [In] ref Guid rguidReason,
        [In, Out] ref IntPtr phwnd);
    [PreserveSig]
    int OnSecurityProblem(
        [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint dwProblem);
}
public class MyWebBrowser : WebBrowser
{
    public static Guid IID_IHttpSecurity
        = new Guid("79eac9d7-bafa-11ce-8c82-00aa004ba90b");
    public static Guid IID_IWindowForBindingUI
        = new Guid("79eac9d5-bafa-11ce-8c82-00aa004ba90b");
    public const int S_OK = 0;
    public const int S_FALSE = 1;
    public const int E_NOINTERFACE = unchecked((int)0x80004002);
    public const int RPC_E_RETRY = unchecked((int)0x80010109);
    protected override WebBrowserSiteBase CreateWebBrowserSiteBase()
    {
        return new MyWebBrowserSite(this);
    }
    class MyWebBrowserSite : WebBrowserSite,
        UCOMIServiceProvider,
        IHttpSecurity,
        IWindowForBindingUI
    {
        private MyWebBrowser myWebBrowser;
        public MyWebBrowserSite(MyWebBrowser myWebBrowser)
            :base(myWebBrowser)
        {
            this.myWebBrowser = myWebBrowser;
        }
        public int QueryService(ref Guid guidService
            , ref Guid riid
            , out IntPtr ppvObject)
        {
            if (riid ==IID_IHttpSecurity)
            {
                ppvObject= Marshal.GetComInterfaceForObject(this
                    , typeof(IHttpSecurity));
                return S_OK;
            }
            if (riid == IID_IWindowForBindingUI)
            {
                ppvObject = Marshal.GetComInterfaceForObject(this
                    , typeof(IWindowForBindingUI));
                return S_OK;
            }
            ppvObject = IntPtr.Zero;
            return E_NOINTERFACE;
        }
        public int GetWindow(ref Guid rguidReason
            , ref IntPtr phwnd)
        {
            if (rguidReason == IID_IHttpSecurity
                || rguidReason == IID_IWindowForBindingUI)
            {
                phwnd = myWebBrowser.Handle;
                return S_OK;
            }
            else
            {
                phwnd = IntPtr.Zero;
                return S_FALSE;
            }
        }
        public int OnSecurityProblem(uint dwProblem)
        {
            //ignore errors
            //undocumented return code, does not work on IE6
            return S_OK;
        }
    }
}
```

And I'm using like this:

```
MyWebBrowser web = new MyWebBrowser();
            web.Navigate("https://...");
            web.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            this.Controls.Add(web);
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: "...but it didn't worked for me". - what does that mean?

Comment: does means that the certificate isn't ignored? I'll edit if it isn't clear

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `ppvObject= Marshal.GetComInterfaceForObject(this                , typeof(IHttpSecurity))`. Does it ever get triggered?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WebBrowser control - ignore SSL errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6933254/webbrowser-control-ignore-ssl-errors)

Comment: This duplicate question doesn't even an accepted answer. Not sure of the author solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to suppress those messages, try setting WebBrowser property ScriptErrorsSuppressed

`webBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true`

This should fix your problem

Also you can see here another way to suppress those messages, with more specific handling

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.scripterrorssuppressed.aspx