# How disable ssl certificate in WebBrowser WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, ssl

How can I disable check certificate on WebBrowser UI control in Windows phone 8. I try ([WebBrowser control - ignore SSL errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6933254/webbrowser-control-ignore-ssl-errors)) but VS don't see class ServicePointManager.